# I want to show the lightbox on only homepage of my blog.but it appears on every page

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I have this code:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js'/>

     <script src='https://gj37765.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/[www.gj37765.blogspot.com]jquery.colorbox-min.js'/>
 <link href='https://gj37765.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/%5Bwww.gj37765.blogspot.com%5Dfbpopup.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if (document.cookie.indexOf(&#39;visited=flase&#39;) == -1) {
            var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
            var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
            document.cookie = &quot;visited=false;expires=&quot; + expires.toUTCString();
        $.colorbox({width:&quot;400px&quot;, inline:true, href:&quot;#mdfb&quot;});
            }
     });
     </script>
```

The code is for a Facebook-like box which appears when a user visits my blog. My blog is on blogger. My problem is that the lightbox of this jquery appears again and again whenever a user sees other posts or refreshes the page. I want it to appear only on the home page of site. I don't know anything about jQuery.

Comment: You have so many errors there e.g. `&#39;` is meant to be a quotation mark, single or double,  as well as `&quot;`

Comment: What is `flase` a ternary type for the bool given? It is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace "false" with "true"

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=false') == -1) {
```

and one more here

```
document.cookie = 'visited=false; expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to see the top address link and compare it...

```
<script>
 if(window.location.href=="www.example.com"){
   // do the reset of your code here....
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=flase') == -1) {
        var fifteenDays = 1000*60*60*24*30;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + fifteenDays);
        document.cookie = 'visited=false;expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
    $.colorbox({width'400px', inline:true, href:'#mdfb'});
        }
   });
 }
</script>
```

copy and paste the above, and replace example.com with your domain name, e.g. "myid.blogspot.com" or however blogspot works :)

Comment: Can you please explain it to me . I dont know anything about jquery. Please . I would really appreciate if you help me !

Comment: ok do you want to display all the time on the main homepage, or do you want to display it only once on the home page, ???

Comment: I want to display it only once on homepage when a visitor visits. but the lightbox appears again wen we move to next page.

Comment: Sorry alot if its irritating because of me. But which code i should i replace with this code which you gave me ? I tried by adding this code if(window.location.href=="troll-me.blogspot.com"){ above jQuery(document).ready(function(){ . But it didnt worked :( Cant see the lightbox on blog

Comment: 'http://www.troll-me.blogspot.com/' should be there or added alert(window.location.href) to see what you should put there, or it could be `http://troll-me.blogspot.com/`

Comment: Thanks for helping . i wasnt able to do it :(